# Batch analysing documents with solr (extracting tf idf information)

Tags: solr

Hi i want to extract the tf-idf values for terms in documents. After a bit of searching i found a request handler in the example configuration that can do that: `http://localhost:8983/solr/tvrh/?q=id:documentid&qt=tvrh&tv=true&tv.all=true`

What i want to do is to batch-analyse documents. This is what i do:

1. sending a new document to the solr update handler with commit=true
2. Querying solr for the term vectors using the above url

The problem is that inserting a docment with commit=true takes about 600ms which is not really acceptable for my usecase.

i then found http://wiki.apache.org/solr/RealTimeGet and tried to combine that with the termvector request handler:

```
<requestHandler name="/tvrh" class="solr.RealTimeGetHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="df">text</str>
      <bool name="tv">true</bool>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>tvComponent</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>
```

But then i get this as response when i try to query the handler: http://pastebin.com/KtB7DBSv I suppose combining those two is not possible?

How can i improve the performance anyway? Any suggestions? Is there another approach to get the tf idf values?

Answer (score 0):

i did not found a solution to the specific problem in the question, but found that using softCommit=true is much more faster.